# Sub that finds Rows with same ID in Col A, then Concatenates to merge values in Col C into single cell with line break deliminater

Tags: vba

I have a VBA that takes all the rows with the same ID in Column 1 and concatenates the data in Column 3 to a single cell with line breaks. The code then deletes the old rows. The code works, but takes 10+ seconds to run. I have about 3-4k rows of data but I was hoping this could run much faster.

```
Sub merge()
Dim lngRow As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
        Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 1
        Dim columnToConcatenate As Integer: columnToConcatenate = 3 'determie which column has the values to merge


        lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes

        Do
            If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then
                .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToConcatenate) & vbNewLine & .Cells(lngRow, columnToConcatenate)
                .Rows(lngRow).Delete
            End If

            lngRow = lngRow - 1
        Loop Until lngRow = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried removing the active sheet reference and turning off events/screen updating. There are no calculations on the sheet. I have also tried sorting the data first.

Any ideas how I can improve efficiency and speed?

Comment: Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first.